# Python3 DTLS Server/Client

Tags: python-3.x, dtls

I am planning to implement a "simple" DTLS tool in python3, which is able to initiate (client) and accept DTLS (server) connections with a PSK as a PoC (later on i am planning to extend it to certificate-based authentication).
I spent days researching libraries that offer this functionality, but i am still not sure what to use. (Any wrapper/library suggestion with documentation/examples are more than welcome).

While it is straightforward to create the DTLS Clients/Servers with the openssl binaries (for example):

`openssl s_server -dtls -accept 1337 -nocert -psk deadbeef -cipher PSK-AES128-CCM8`

for the server (with a specific ciphersuite) and

`openssl s_client -dtls -connect 127.0.0.1:1337 -psk deadbeef -cipher PSK-AES128-CCM8`

for the client, i am struggling to find do this with python. (pyopenssl offers no DTLS support) Are there any concrete examples for an implementation using a widly supported library/wrapper? (There are some Coap/IoT libraries out there focussing on the client side (aiocoap), but for my idea it is neccessary to implement both sides)

Comment: As a side note, aiocoap now does also handle the server side of DTLS, albeit still only with PSK support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [mbedTLS](https://tls.mbed.org/) (former PolarSSL). They offer a quite extensive [Python3 wrapper](https://github.com/Synss/python-mbedtls) that offering almost all of mbedTLS functionality. The readme offers a very useful DTLS sample implementation featuring authentication using a psk and/or certs.